# How to extract characters from strings

Tags: python

I run the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(['ip', 'addr'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['grep', 'enp'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
output=p2.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

and I get the output:

```
b'7: enp0s20f0u1c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000\n    inet 172.20.10.2/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic enp0s20f0u1c4i2\n'
```

How to extract the characters *enp0s20f0u1c4i2* from the string of this output?

Comment: `output.split(':')[1].strip()`

Comment: `output.split()[-1].strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the string `output` always has that same format, you could use the split function to split in `:`, take the first element and then *clean* the string to remove the spaces and `\n`. Similarly you could split by space  and get the last element of the split (it seems the string you are looking for appears twice?)

So `output.split(':')[1].strip()` or `output.split(' ')[-1].strip()`.